# Heat correlation matrix VBA

Tags: vba, matrix

I have created a functon to return matrix correlation of a data set, but I want this matrix to have colors like the one you can do using R o Python

[image]

```
Function MCORRELATION(Rango As Range) As Variant
 Dim x As Variant, y As Variant, s As Integer, T As Integer, C() As Variant
 ReDim C(Rango.Columns.Count, Rango.Columns.Count)
 For i = 1 To Rango.Columns.Count Step 1
  For j = 1 To i Step 1
  C(i, j) = Application.Correl(Application.Index(Rango, , i), 
   Application.Index(Rango, , j))
 Next j
Next i
 MCORRELATION = C
End Function
```

How can I achieve that **using conditional formating with VBA**?

Comment: Try using conditional formatting

Comment: @TimWilliams yep this is what I want but my question is if it is possible by ussing vba

Comment: Yes it is - you can record a macro while adding the CF and use the resulting code